# cakephp having condition in find

Tags: cakephp, find, having

can someone help me, and show me how to insert BEETWEN in having clausule in cakephp

exampleo of my codE:

```
$zaduzenja = $this->Zaduzenja->find('all',array(
                'conditions' => array(
                        'Zaduzenja.placeno' => 0 ),
                'fields' => array('Zaduzenja.obveznici_id', 'SUM(Zaduzenja.zaduzenje) as dug'),
                'group' => 'Zaduzenja.obveznici_id HAVING array(dug BETWEEN ? AND ? => array('.$iznosOd,$iznosDo)'

        ));
```

but this not working, i only want Calculated column "dug" to check if Dug >=$temp 1 AND Dug <=$temp2, but this is posible only in group with having clausule

Comment: `SUM(Zaduzenja.zaduzenje) as dug` => that should be a virtual field! See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why not simply this?

```
$db = $this->Zaduzenja->getDataSource();

$iznosOd = $db->value($iznosOd, 'double');  // quotes and escapes input to avoid SQL injections
$iznosDo = $db->value($iznosDo, 'double');  // ditto

$zaduzenja = $this->Zaduzenja->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Zaduzenja.placeno' => 0 
        ),
        'fields' => array(
            'Zaduzenja.obveznici_id', 
            'SUM(Zaduzenja.zaduzenje) as dug'
        ),
        'group' => "Zaduzenja.obveznici_id HAVING dug BETWEEN $iznosOd AND $iznosDo"
    )
);
```

Comment: how i can add one more parametaers date
this like iznosOd iznosDo,
DateOd DateDo ??

Comment: how i can add one more parametaers date this like iznosOd iznosDo, DateOd DateDo ??

Comment: where do you want to add those parameters? In where condition or in Having condition. Please explain better

Comment: well, i have to check dates, i only need SUM(Dug) where date are in right range, actually i have to add parameters in where condition?

Comment: ...our daily dose of SQL injection vulnerabilities. Please [**escape the input**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-DboSource.html#_value) properly.

Comment: Do not use on paginated sets, it completely ruins pagination!

Answer (score -1):

Hi change your query as shown below:

```
$zaduzenja = $this->Zaduzenja->find('all',array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                            'Zaduzenja.placeno' => 0
                             ),
                    'fields' => array(
                            'Zaduzenja.obveznici_id',
                            'SUM(Zaduzenja.zaduzenje) as dug'
                            ),
                    'group' => 'Zaduzenja.obveznici_id having dug Between '.$temp_1.' and '.$temp2

            ));
```

Iinjoy

Comment: i changed, but i get this error:
General error: 1 misuse of aggregate: SUM()
i think i have to use HAVING in 'group'

Comment: The same [SQL injection vulnerability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797240/cakephp-having-condition-in-find#comment31184034_20797718) as in arilias answer...

Comment: @ndm you cannot do SQL injection in the above query becoz everytime you put something in $tem_1 or in $temp_2, it will come under group statement...and that is the beauty of CakePHP database wrapper...Thanks for enlightenment anyways...

Comment: It's beautiful when done right, but this is the wrong way, of course you can inject SQL in it, just give it a try.