# cakephp set condition on MAX()

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I need max submitted orders in the last 30 days. max field is a virtualField.

```
public $virtualFields = array(
        'max_submitted' => "MAX(`WorkRecord`.`submitted`)"
    );

I get error #1054 - Unknown column 'WorkRecord.max_submitted' in 'field list' 


SELECT `WorkRecord`.`id`, `Order`.`fee`, `Order`.`order_id`, 
       `Order`.`min_sources`, `Order`.`min_references`, `Order`.`am_level`,
       `Order`.`am_standard`, `Order`.`am_type`, `Order`.`am_subject`, `Order`.`am_word_count`,
       `Order`.`ref_style`, `Order`.`service`, `BriefInstalment`.`deadline`, 
       `BriefInstalment`.`id`, (MAX(`WorkRecord`.`submitted`)) AS `WorkRecord__max_submitted` 
FROM `writers`.`work_records` AS `WorkRecord` 
RIGHT JOIN `torg`.`temp_orders` AS `Order` ON (`Order`.`order_id` = `WorkRecord`.`order_id` AND `Order`.`status2` > 2 AND `Order`.`am_type` NOT LIKE '%phd%') LEFT JOIN `writers`.`brief_instalments` AS `BriefInstalment` ON (`WorkRecord`.`brief_instalment_id` = `BriefInstalment`.`id`) 
WHERE `WorkRecord`.`writer_id` = 7827 
       AND `WorkRecord`.`withdrawn` IS NULL 
       AND `WorkRecord`.`max_submitted` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() GROUP BY `Order`.`order_id`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use aggregate function results in `where` clauses, because the results of the aggregate (e.g. `max()`) will NOT be available when the where clause is being applied.

Move the max() to a `having:

```
SELECT ..., max(foo) AS foo
FROM ...
WHERE ...
HAVING foo BETWEEN ...
```

`having` is basically applied as the last step just before the results are sent over the client. By that time, all of the calculations/aggregations are done.

Comment: spot the difference:  ``AS `WorkRecord__max_submitted` `` and ``AND `WorkRecord`.`max_submitted` ``

Comment: Yes I know. I think you are right. I have written it. just checking the data if it's correct

Comment: Thank you for your help buddy. with your answer I followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797240/cakephp-having-condition-in-find   for Cakphp

Answer (score 0):

For others. Here is what I should have done.

```
$workRecords = $this->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array(
                'WorkRecord.id', 'MAX(`WorkRecord`.`submitted`) AS submitted', 
                'Order.fee', 'Order.order_id', 'Order.min_sources', 'Order.min_references', 'Order.am_level', 'Order.am_standard',
                'Order.am_type', 'Order.am_subject', 'Order.am_word_count', 'Order.ref_style', 'Order.service'
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'WorkRecord.writer_id' => $userId,
                'WorkRecord.withdrawn IS NULL'
            ),
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'torg.temp_orders',
                    'alias' => 'Order',
                    'type' => 'RIGHT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Order.order_id = WorkRecord.order_id',
                        'Order.status2 >' => 2,
                        "Order.am_type NOT LIKE '%phd%'"
                    )
                )
            ),
            'contain' => array(
                'BriefInstalment.deadline'
            ),
            'group' => array(
                'Order.order_id HAVING `submitted` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()'
            )
        ));
```